Pandas to polars fails
I am getting data from DBnomics which returns it as pandas df. I prefer polars, and so do pl.from_pandas(df) and that sometimes fails with TypeError: 'float' object cannot be converted to 'PyString'
here is the code
import pandas as pd
from dbnomics import fetch_series
import polars as pl
df= fetch_series("WB/WDI/A-NY.GDP.MKTP.CD-RUS")
df = pl.from_pandas(df)

I could fix it in this specific case, but is there a way to robustly convert pandas to polars?

Can you post an example of a dataframe that throws this error? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

thanks, you can get dataframe from the vendor with the code provided

Don't ask users to install some package just to answer your question. Instead, add a minimal representation of your df that throws the error when using pl.from_pandas.

df = pl.DataFrame({"foo": ["NA", 2.0]}) is a minimal example. I'm not sure what is supposed to happen in this case. I've added debug info as an "answer" below as it was too large for a comment - but this is probably something that needs to be asked to Polars people directly, e.g. Discord/Github?

@jqurious: I take it you mean df = pd.DataFrame({"foo": ["NA", 2.0]}) :). It's interesting that this will work: pl.DataFrame(df.to_dict('list'), schema_overrides={'foo': pl.Float64}, strict=False). One would have expected pl.from_pandas to have a strict parameter as well.

Sorry @ouroboros1, was not aware of the etiquette. I am not an expert, and would not have been able to diagnose this at the level of the other comments. I just assumed that one should be able to convert pandas to polars without problems. Will solve this by coding this in pandas only. Best, jack.

@jackstrauss The main problem is that pandas allows you to hold mixed types (e.g. strings and numbers) together:pd.Series(["NA", 2.0]) but Polars does not.

Thanks @jqurious that makes sense. Can see why this is tricky,

I'm not sure if this is a "bug" or not?
The problem with this specific example, is the original_value column contains the string "NA" and float values.
>>> df["original_value"]
0                       NA
1                       NA
2                       NA
3                       NA
4                       NA
              ...         
59    1693115002708.320068
60    1493075894362.139893
61    1843392293734.379883
62    2266029240645.339844
63    2021421476035.419922
Name: original_value, Length: 64, dtype: object

Polars columns (Series) can only have a single type, and it is trying to convert this to str - which fails due to the float values.
Replacing NA with an actual NaN value allows it to succeed.
df = pl.from_pandas(
    df.assign(original_value=df["original_value"].replace("NA", float("nan"))))
)

shape: (64, 16)
┌────────────┬───────────────┬──────────────┬──────────────────────────────┬───┬─────────┬───────────────────┬───────────────────┬────────────────────┐
│ @frequency ┆ provider_code ┆ dataset_code ┆ dataset_name                 ┆ … ┆ country ┆ frequency (label) ┆ indicator (label) ┆ country (label)    │
│ ---        ┆ ---           ┆ ---          ┆ ---                          ┆   ┆ ---     ┆ ---               ┆ ---               ┆ ---                │
│ str        ┆ str           ┆ str          ┆ str                          ┆   ┆ str     ┆ str               ┆ str               ┆ str                │
╞════════════╪═══════════════╪══════════════╪══════════════════════════════╪═══╪═════════╪═══════════════════╪═══════════════════╪════════════════════╡
│ annual     ┆ WB            ┆ WDI          ┆ World Development Indicators ┆ … ┆ RUS     ┆ Annual            ┆ GDP (current US$) ┆ Russian Federation │
│ annual     ┆ WB            ┆ WDI          ┆ World Development Indicators ┆ … ┆ RUS     ┆ Annual            ┆ GDP (current US$) ┆ Russian Federation │
│ annual     ┆ WB            ┆ WDI          ┆ World Development Indicators ┆ … ┆ RUS     ┆ Annual            ┆ GDP (current US$) ┆ Russian Federation │
│ annual     ┆ WB            ┆ WDI          ┆ World Development Indicators ┆ … ┆ RUS     ┆ Annual            ┆ GDP (current US$) ┆ Russian Federation │
│ annual     ┆ WB            ┆ WDI          ┆ World Development Indicators ┆ … ┆ RUS     ┆ Annual            ┆ GDP (current US$) ┆ Russian Federation │
│ …          ┆ …             ┆ …            ┆ …                            ┆ … ┆ …       ┆ …                 ┆ …                 ┆ …                  │
│ annual     ┆ WB            ┆ WDI          ┆ World Development Indicators ┆ … ┆ RUS     ┆ Annual            ┆ GDP (current US$) ┆ Russian Federation │
│ annual     ┆ WB            ┆ WDI          ┆ World Development Indicators ┆ … ┆ RUS     ┆ Annual            ┆ GDP (current US$) ┆ Russian Federation │
│ annual     ┆ WB            ┆ WDI          ┆ World Development Indicators ┆ … ┆ RUS     ┆ Annual            ┆ GDP (current US$) ┆ Russian Federation │
│ annual     ┆ WB            ┆ WDI          ┆ World Development Indicators ┆ … ┆ RUS     ┆ Annual            ┆ GDP (current US$) ┆ Russian Federation │
│ annual     ┆ WB            ┆ WDI          ┆ World Development Indicators ┆ … ┆ RUS     ┆ Annual            ┆ GDP (current US$) ┆ Russian Federation │
└────────────┴───────────────┴──────────────┴──────────────────────────────┴───┴─────────┴───────────────────┴───────────────────┴────────────────────┘

>>> df["original_value"]
shape: (64,)
Series: 'original_value' [f64]
[
    null
    null
    null
    null
    null
    …
    1.6931e12
    1.4931e12
    1.8434e12
    2.2660e12
    2.0214e12
]

DuckDB for example, interprets the column to be of type String.
>>> duckdb.sql("from df").pl()["original_value"]
shape: (64,)
Series: 'original_value' [str]
[
    "NA"
    "NA"
    "NA"
    "NA"
    "NA"
    …
    "1693115002708.32"
    "1493075894362.14"
    "1843392293734.38"
    "2266029240645.34"
    "2021421476035.42"
]

It's not clear to me what the correct behaviour is here.

Thanks @jqurious, that makes sense. To me, polars should do it the same way as pandas.  I tried the R version of the vendor api, and both data.tables and dataframes treat it in the same as pandas.
